# Differentiating $2^{n/100}$ using the chain rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

I am trying to find the derivative of $2^{n/100}$ with respect to $n$. I know that I have to use the chain rule to differentiate this.

I have:

$$f(n) = 2^{n/100} = e^{\ln2 \cdot n/100}$$

For my $u$, I have set it to $\ln2 \cdot (n/100)$.

$$\begin{align}
df/du &= e^{ln2 \cdot n/100}\\
du/dn &= \ln2/100\\
df/dn &= e^{\ln2 \cdot n/100} \cdot \ln2/100
\end{align}$$

However, I checked the answer and the derivative is supposed to be:

$$df/dn = 1/25 \cdot 2^{n/100 - 2} \cdot \ln2$$

I am not sure how the above answer was derived. Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: These answers are equivalent. Do you see how?

Comment: No, I don't. I know that e^ln2 = 2, but I'm not sure how the -2 came in 2^((n/100)-2)

Comment: From the index laws, $x^{a-b} \equiv \frac{x^a}{x^b}$. So $2^{(n/100)-2}$ becomes $\frac{1}{4}\cdot 2^{n/100}$.

Comment: Just a comment here,  interesting that you name the variable $n$, which is merely a symbol for natural numbers! It is your taste or written in a book?

Comment: It was written in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's merely a simplification thing. We have, in your answer,

$$e^{\ln2\cdot n/100}\cdot\frac{\ln2}{100}$$

First, we note that $e^{\ln(2)} = 2$. Then this becomes

$$2^{n/100}\cdot\frac{\ln2}{100}$$

Next, we note that $100 = 2^2 \cdot 25$. Thus,

$$2^{n/100}\cdot\frac{\ln2}{100} = 2^{n/100}\cdot\frac{\ln2}{25} \cdot \frac{1}{2^2}$$

We can thus subtract $2$ from the exponent of the $2^{n/100}$. Thus, we obtain

$$ 2^{n/100 - 2}\cdot\frac{\ln2}{25}$$

the answer you were given.

Answer (score 1):

$$1/25 \cdot 2^{n/100 - 2} \cdot \ln2=1/25 \cdot 2^{-2} \cdot 2^{n/100} \cdot \ln2=e^{\ln 2 \cdot n/100} \cdot \ln2/100$$

So your answer is the same as the standard answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where logarithmic differentiation makes life much easier.

Making the problem more general
$$y=a ^{bn}\implies \log(y)=b  \log(a)\,n$$ Diffentiate both sides
$$\frac {y'}y=b  \log(a)\implies y'=b  \log(a)\,a^{bn}$$